# How to replace white character by character using bean shell in Jmeter?

Tags: regex, jmeter

I have a variable i.e, "Classification" and it`s value is "Vol 4" and I needs to replace white space with "+" character in "Classification" variable. So, I required to write a script in bean shell to replace white space character by character.

Can anyone help me in this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that you're looking for URL encoding function. There are 2 ways to go:

1. Easy one - use JMeter's function to encode the URL. Assuming that you have "Classification" variable it'll be something like `${__urlencode(${Classification})}`
2. Harder (but more flexible) one - use Beanshell to do the same.

Example Beanshell code:

```
import java.net.URLEncoder; // import required class

String classification = vars.get("Classification").toString(); // obtain value of "Classification" variable
String encoded = URLEncoder.encode(classification,    System.getProperty("file.encoding")); // encode "Classification variable and save result to "encoded" string
vars.put("Classificatoin",encoded); // replace "Classification" variable with new value
```

If you need just replacing single or multiple characters - see the solution is in previous answer.

References:

- [__urlEncode()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__urlencode) JMeter Function
- [How to use Beanshell](http://blazemeter.com/blog/queen-jmeters-built-componentshow-use-beanshell) guide
- [String](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html) Java class documentation

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is simply use java string classes for string operations defined like below,

```
var tt=vars.get("ORIGINAL_STRING_KEY");
log.info("ORIGINAL STRING :"+tt);
java.lang.String st=new java.lang.String(tt) ;
st=st.replace(" ","+");
log.info("EDITED STRING :"+st);
```

**OUTPUT : "TEST STRING" >> "TEST+STRING"**

Hope this may help you.. :)

Answer (score 0):

use javascript inside either JSR223 sampler or direct function

```
var res = encodeURIComponent(vars.get("yourStringInveriable"));
```