# How to find and replace a substring in sampler's response for web services?

Tags: jmeter

I am using two soap/xml request samplers wherein response of one is to be used in request of the other. The issue is that the response of Sampler1 contains multiple occurrences of "a:" which has to be replaced by "eas1:" which can be used in Sampler2. Kindly suggest a solution.

I tried using beanshell postprocessor but could not come to any positive result.

Comment: See the following Answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22632049/how-to-replace-white-character-by-character-using-bean-shell-in-jmeter

Answer (score 2):

1. Add [JSR223 PostProcessor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_PostProcessor) as a child of the **Sampler1**
2. Put the following code into "Script" area

   ```
   def response = prev.getResponseDataAsString()
   def request = response.replaceAll('a:', 'eas1:')
   vars.put('request', request)
   ```
3. Use `${request}` in the "Body Data" section of the **Sampler2**

References:

- `prev` is a shorthand to [SampleResult](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/samplers/SampleResult.html) class instance which provides access to the parent Sampler result
- `vars` is a shorthand to [JMeterVariables](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/threads/JMeterVariables.html) class instance, it provides read/write access to JMeter Variables
- [String.replaceAll()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-) method reference
- [Groovy is the New Black](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black) - guide to Groovy scripting in JMeter